# Objectify - ofy() in method defined outside of transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

A basic transaction looks like this:

```
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Work;

// If you don't need to return a value, you can use VoidWork
Thing th = ofy().transact(new Work<Thing>() {
    public Thing run() {
        Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();
        thing.modify();
        ofy().save().entity(thing);
    }
});
```

When ofy().load() and other ofy() methods called from within the transaction they have all the benefits of the transaction, such as being atomic. **However, does using a Util method that contains a ofy() method escape the transaction?** Something like the following.

```
// If you don't need to return a value, you can use VoidWork
Thing th = ofy().transact(new Work<Thing>() {
    public Thing run() {
        Util.modify(thingKey);
    }
});
```

Where Util is defined somewhere like so.

```
public class Util {

    public static modify(thingKey) {
        Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();
        thing.modify();
        ofy().save().entity(thing);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two cases you describe are exactly equivalent.

If you wish to run something outside of the transaction then Objectify provides a .transactionless() method to "escape" the transactional context.

Comment: I figured that much, but I needed to be sure before I start programming as such. For my piece of mind, could you elaborate on how this works or link documentation that does? Thanks.

Comment: The second case is just an abstraction, so it must work the same - it's more a pure java topic.  However to help with understanding you can trace with a debugger into the transact call and you'll find some setup and completion code _around_ your Work implementation run() method call.  That code sets some state that ofy() then is aware of so things work.